# Can't make Qt Creator Work

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've downloaded and installed Qt Creator from its online installer and the latest version but when i try to create a Qt Console Application i get the following error. I haven't touched options. The picture is an error from when i tried to open a file from my professor but i get the same error when i try to create a new one. It could be pretty simple but its the 1st time im using this program as a student and have no idea whats going on. Thanks in regards for your time[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87dTO.png)

Comment: Have you already downloaded Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Qt Creator with MSVC Compiler (Visual Studio), you need to also download the Visual Studio Compiler. Qt for MSVC doesn't come with a compiler.

It seems that you are trying to compile with VS 2017. You can Download Visual Studio 2017 from: https://www.visualstudio.com/es/downloads/
Express is free, the other two are paid, but don't download VS Code, it's for another purpose.

Alternatively, you can download only the compiler from: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools It's ligther but you don't get the IDE.

Also, for debugging, if you are on x86 or x64, download Windows CDB from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

After you install this, you can reboot Qt and then it will show it has the appropiate compiler and debugger, like this (note that I use VS 2013):

[image: Example of a configured Qt Kit]

There is another option if you don't want to download or use Visual Studio. Go to the Qt Maintenance Tool (uninstaller), Add or remove components, then install MinGW binaries of your favorite Qt Version, like this:

[image: MinGW Qt 5.10.1]

MinGW is free and it comes bundled with Qt, so you can build and run (and debug!) right away.